# How to expand my render view camera？

Tags: camera

[image]My rendering angle has already been determined, and I don't want to change the focal length of the camera to expand the upper and lower range of the rendering angle of view.
in Scene，i can change resolution X to expand my camera view,but changing Y value can't expand do the same thing.
and in camera lens change shift X or Y just can shift up/down,it couldn't  expand at the same time.[image]

Comment: i don't understand "but changing Y value can't expand do the same thing" -> i think this can do it and this is what you are searching for. Maybe show us how you change your resolution (in scene) and this won't make your y-view for your camera bigger - maybe a yt video or some screenshots. thx.

Comment: Hi Chris, I add another image to explain my question, when i change Y, it scale my view, not to expand, i am very confuse that and i want to know how to expand not scale. thanks~